# Workaround when hashcode crosses the integer boundary

Tags: java, integer, hashcode

I have a `POJO` having ~450 fields and I'm trying to compare instances of this POJO using hascode. I've generated the overridden `hashCode()` method with eclipse. In quite a few cases the generated hashcode is crossing the integer boundary. As a result, it's getting difficult to perform the comparison. What's the workaround?

The `hashCode()` method is as follows:

```
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((stringOne == null) ? 0 : stringOne.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + intOne;
    result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(someArray);
    result = prime * result + ((stringTwo == null) ? 0 : stringTwo.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + intTwo;
    result = prime * result + intThree;
    result = prime * result + ((stringThree == null) ? 0 : stringThree.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((stringFour == null) ? 0 : stringFour.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((stringFive == null) ? 0 : stringFive.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((objectOne == null) ? 0 : objectOne.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((objectTwo == null) ? 0 : objectTwo.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In Java, integers should have the same size on all platforms, shouldn't they? So an overflow will result in the same result, thus they won't cause any issues upon comparison. Can you give an example in which case comparison did not work for you?

Comment: BTW: see the [god object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) anti-pattern. Maybe you can split it into smaller pieces?

Comment: I didn't understand this part -- "So an overflow will result in the same result". Please elaborate.

Comment: if two objects of your 450 fields class are identical, they will have identical overflow

Comment: The result of an integer overflow should end up with the same number. (If all JVMs handle the overflow in the same way)

Comment: My concern is, this overflowed value of an instance can be equal to the not-overflowed value of another instance. In that scenario, they will deemed as same objects, though they are not. How to handle such situations?

Comment: `hashCode()` does not determine equality of two objects, `equals(Object)` does. Hash code clashes should be avoided for efficiency, but having the same hash code is not informative if you want to check whether two objects are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Integer overflow is a normal part of `hashCode()` calculations. It is not a problem.

For example, the `hashCode()` of a `String` is often negative.

```
System.out.println("The hashCode() of this String is negative".hashCode());
```

If a `hashCode()` calculation can overflow, obviously that can mean that unequal `Object`s can have the same `hashCode`, but this can happen *without* overflow. For example, both of these print `true`.

```
System.out.println("Aa".hashCode() == "BB".hashCode());
System.out.println(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2)).hashCode() == Collections.singleton(3).hashCode());
```

The only requirement is that equal objects should have the same `hashCode`. There is no requirement that different objects should have different `hashCode`s.

`hashCode()` and `equals()` should also be quick. You can improve the performance of `equals()` by comparing the fields most likely to be different first and returning early. You can't do this with `hashCode()` because the calculation must involve all the relevant fields. If your class has 450 fields, you may want to consider caching the result of `hashCode()` or, better, refactoring your class into smaller units.

The other thing to consider is whether you need to override these methods at all. It is only absolutely necessary if the objects are going to used as keys in a hash based container, such as `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to use a different method to compute the hashcode. For instance, you could `xor` the hashcodes of your 450 fields (btw: wow!), but without knowing more about your object it's hard to say whether that would be a good approach for your particular case.

Ideally, since hashcodes are used for hashing, objects that are not equal should also with high probability produce different hashcodes.

Comment: Well, I'm actually trying to find the difference between two lists of this POJO. As far I know, the `AbstractSet.removeAll()` method calls the `hashCode()` method internally. Will different hashcode method be a solution in this case?

Comment: I suggest to read the API documentation for `hashCode()` and `equals()` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) `AbstractSet.removeAll()` calls both: `hashCode` for fast access and `equals` to check identity. Your POJO should thus implement both so that they behave as specified in the API documentation.

Comment: Both are implemented. That's not the concern here.

Comment: The concern is that you may not understand fully how these two methods interact, given your first comment. You should make sure that their implementation is according to the specification.